# ServiceStack not showing Metadata page

Tags: c#, asp.net, metadata, servicestack

This is my first Service in ServiceStack.

```
public class UserServiceHost : AppHostBase
        {
            public UserServiceHost() : base("UserServiceHost", typeof(UserService).Assembly) { }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
            {
                // Configure Application
            }
        }

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new UserServiceHost().Init();
        }
```

Very simple. The file UserService is the same project and directory of the Global.Asax.

When I run the project the metadata page is not displayed. The directory listing of the site is displayed.

In fact when I insert the /metadata I receive a 404.

My project is a ASP.Net Web Application. I have included ServiceStack, everything seems ok.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please adjust your web.config like following:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 (and above?) -->
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```